# Angular event not triggered second time

Tags: angular, components, click, eventemitter

I have a question.

Why the second time I press click on parent component the event is not triggered?

for example I have first component for parent

```
<app-page>
 <div *ngFor="let object of objects$ | ngrxPush">
      <app-parent>
           <div class="add-button">
             <button  
               (click)="onAddBtnClick(object)"
               mat-icon-button
             >
             </button>
           </div>
     </app-parent>
     <app-child-container
           [viewChildContainer]="object.showChildContiner"
          (containerClickOutside)="onContainerClick(object)"
         >
     </app-child-container>  
  </div>
 </app-page>
```

In .ts file for parent

```
onAddBtnClick(object: Object): void {
     object.showChildContiner = true;
}

onContainerClick(object): void {
     object.showChildContiner = false;
}
```

In the child container

```
  <div class="child-container">
     <app-grandson-component
       *ngIf="viewChildContainer"
        (containerClickOutside)="containerClickOutside($event)"
        >
     </app-grandson-component>
  </div>
```

In the child.ts

```
   @Input() viewChildContainer: boolean;

   onGrandSonEmit(grandChildTextAreaText: string): void {
       this.containerClickOutside.emit(grandChildTextAreaText);
  }
```

In the grandson

```
 <div (focusout)="onFocusOut()">
      <textarea
         matInput
         cdkTextareaAutosize
         #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
         #textarea
         [(ngModel)]="textareaText"
       ></textarea>
  </div>
```

In the grandson.ts

```
 @ViewChild('textarea', { static: false }) textarea: ElementRef;
 @Output() onGrandSonEmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 noteText: string;

 onFocusOut(): void {
    this.onGrandSonEmit.emit(this.textarea.nativeElement.value);
   }
 }
```

Scenario

First time I click onAddBtnClick from the parent and the child and grandson components get on the view.

The second time I click on onAddBtnClick it will call focusOut from the grandson component emit everithing until the parent, but the event for onAddBtnClick will not get triggered.

Any idea,
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the textarea you are editing is located above the add-button you are clicking on the 2nd click,
the 'focusOut'-event of the editing textarea will hide the textarea and as result, the button you are clicking moves away upwards directly before the click hits him.

So your 'click' is not going to the add-button but to the location where the 'add-button' was when you clicked.

But if you click an add-button on top of the editing textarea, it will work (onAddBtnClick is called) as the clicked button will not be moved.

**Possible solution:** Instead of using the 'focusOut'-event you could use only the 'onAddBtnClick' function and set 'showChildContiner' to false on all objects except the clicked one. (Only if you can store them in your controller instead of directly use the observable).

Comment: You need to set more information, a portion of code that you tried to implemented or is causing problems. Also is better to set tags with the languages, frameworks, etc. that you are using, It allow us to show to people that know more about this fields.